# Visual Studio combo box dropdown list is only displaying 1 item/

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress, bind

I want my list to have 2 genders- boy and girl. I want the binded value to display automatically in the textbox, but both genders to display in the dropdown list.However, now I am only getting 1 gender in the dropdown list (the one binded).

```
this.person.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedItem", this.Bind, "name1", true));
this.person.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.Bind, "name1", true));
this.person.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Tag", this.Bind, "name1", true));
this.person.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.Bind, "name1", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
this.person.DataSource = this.Bind;
this.person.DisplayMember = "name";
this.person.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.person.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(360, 888);
this.person.Name = "FlagRMEdit";
this.person.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1112, 271);
this.person.TabIndex = 551;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of ways to accomplish this.  The easiest way is probably to hard code your options in the dropdown control on the aspx page itself, rather than doing it from code-behind.

```
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value">
<asp:ListItem Value="Value 1" Text="girl">Girl</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Value 2" Text="boy">Boy</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: If you carefully take a look at code snippet in question then you can realise that question is about `System.Windows.Forms` platform.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be mixing data binding with the drop down values.  Mind you, you **can** bind your drop-down list to a collection within .NET, but with such a static list of choices (Male, Female), a data-bound list of options is probably overkill.

The binding you listed will allow the choice in the combo box to bind automatically to the object, which is good.  However, to control what items can be selected, you want the `Items` property of the combo box.

If this is a windows control, then it's simply `Items`:

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "Boy", "Girl"});
```

If it's a Dev Express control, then the `Items` Property is accessed via `Properties`:

```
comboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "Boy", "Girl"});
```

These both can be done through the designer, as well:

[image]